# Access corporate calendar via outlook API

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365api, outlook-restapi

**Situation:**

- Company uses Microsoft Exchange Server
- Company has the above accounts for each meeting room
- Uses Outlook 2013

**Problem:**

For me to book a meeting room, I have to go to my calendar in outlook client, start a new meeting, invite a list of rooms, go to the scheduling assistant, and see if any of the rooms has the desired time slot available.

**Question:**

Can I in anyway utilize the office365 [RESTAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations), or any other API to access those room account's calendar, so I can use the response to make some UI to display the availability of meeting rooms.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Where is your code running? Client machine or server?

Comment: No code yet but it will be running on client for sure, I don't have access to the corporate server.

Answer (score 1):

The [`FindMeetingTimes` action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#find-meeting-times-preview) is available on the `beta` endpoint for the Calendar REST API. If you add your desired rooms as resource attendees to the request, it should give you back meeting suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Jason, this might sound like a newbie question, but when reading the requirements it mentions: "This operation is currently in preview and available in only the beta version. It applies to only Office 365 mailboxes (on Azure AD) and not to Microsoft accounts."

The corporate exchange server is probably hosted internally? Will I be able to use the API in this situation still? Thanks!

Comment: Ah. If it's an on-premises installation of Exchange, then the Office 365 REST API isn't available. In that case you want to investigate Exchange Web Services (EWS).